# How can I display the current score in the next level of the game?

Tags: javascript, html

We are developing a hidden object game as a project and we only have a little knowledge about JavaScript. We would like to display the score of the current level within the next level.

Here is the code for the score, it is functional but we need to display the score on the next page.

```
var score_black = 0;

document.onkeydown = key_control;

function remove_score_black(){
    score_black-=50;

    document.getElementById('boldStuff_1').innerHTML = score_black;
}
function add_score_black(){
    score_black+=100;

    document.getElementById('boldStuff_1').innerHTML = score_black;
}

</script>
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "displaying the score to" something.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy, what I mean is to call the score of level 1 on the next stage of the game.

Comment: What server-side programming language are you using? PHP maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Create another variable, e.g.:

```
var userScore = 0; // never reset
var score_black = 0;
```

You can deduct and add points to the userScore, but *never* do this:

```
if (newLevelOrSomething) {
    score_black = 0;
    userScore = 0;
}
```

Just do this,

```
if (newLevelOrSomething) {
    score_black = 0;
}
```

If you are asking about sending a variable to the next page, you can do this:

```
function whatever() {
    document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "<a href='someplace.php?score="score_black"' title='stuff'>Next Page</a>";
}
```

On the next page (.php), add this:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['score'];
?>
```

Then echo the score into an html input or something